# Handling InvalidPropertyException with @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are trying to resolve issues related to a security scan.  It is considered a vulnerability to expose any information about underlying classes.  The scanner is sending invalid data to this endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/accountKey", params = "update")
public String accountKeyUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("accountKeyForm") AccountKeyForm key, BindingResult bindingResult, Authentication authentication)
```

The invalid input looks like this, where "description" is a valid key in the entity, but adding "[]" to the end of the property name in the POST data is causing the parsing error:

```
description[]:
```

The server returns the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-20T14:28:36.653Z",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Invalid property 'description[]' of bean class 
[com.imsweb.seerapi.account.AccountKeyForm]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'description[]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was []",
"path": "/accountKey/"
}
```

This is what appears in the log:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'description[]' of bean class [com.imsweb.seerapi.account.AccountKeyForm]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'description[]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was []
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processKeyedProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:375) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:275) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:839) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:735) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:153) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

The issue is that I cannot find a way to gracefully handle the invalid input.  It looks like it happens when the @ModelAttribute is converting the POST body into an AccountKeyForm.  That is before it gets inside the controller method.  I would prefer to handle the error and just forward them to another page.  Alternatively if the message said

```
"message": "Invalid property 'description[]'"
```

That would be fine as well.

UPDATE:

I can trap that specific exception using an @ExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class WebControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidPropertyException.class)
    public String handleBadPropertyException() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

That means I will just get a generic message.  That will not pick up other types of exceptions that may fall through the cracks.  Is there a better way?

UPDATE:

Here is the entity class.  It is a simple bean with two properties.

```
public class AccountKeyForm {

    private String _apiKey;
    private String _description;

    public AccountKeyForm() {
    }

    public AccountKeyForm(String apiKey) {
        _apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public AccountKeyForm(String apiKey, String description) {
        _apiKey = apiKey;
        _description = description;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return _apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        _apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    @Size(max = 256)
    public String getDescription() {
        return _description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        _description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the cleanest way to go, to me.

Comment: Please showcode for your enitity class.You can bind a handler which cause to give binding result.error() .

Comment: @SHIVOMPANDEY I updated the description with the entity class.  There is not much to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is indeed to wrap the exception using the `ControllerAdvice`, but you need to tweak the response to your needs.

So, instead of returning a `String`, you should return a full `ResponseEntity` with a `httpStatus` and `body`. The `body` should be populated with an `ErrorResponse` where you can define your domain error code if you have something like that and your custom message.

Something like the code below should work.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class WebControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidPropertyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(InvalidPropertyException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus)
            .body(new ErrorResponse(errorCode, message));
    }
}

public class ErrorResponse {

   private final String code;
   private final String message;

   public ErrorResponse(String code, String message) {
       this.code = code;
       this.message = message;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clearing saying the following

`Property referenced in indexed property path 'description[]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was []`

Which means that the description field which is being sent from the request is of type array/List/map, so accordingly,you have to change the Model class AccountKeyForm description 
from  `private String _description;` to  `private List<String> _description;` or 
`private Map<String> _description;` you will need to figure out what collection type is being sent :)

or you'll have to modify how the request is being sent and ensure that it send only String type and not of List/Map type
The former is an easier solution.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: My question is not why this is happening.  I know why.  This was triggered by a security scan which was intentionally probing for vulnerabilities.  The issue is the error message is returning information with class names in the message and that can be considered a vulnerability since it could give an attacker information about how the application is set up.  The application returning the error is correct.  The message just says too much.

Comment: If the message says too much...then you have to encrypt the message,that's the only way you can prevent it from being read, if being attacked, as for handling the exceptions you will know all/most of the use cases for description -@ExceptionHandler(InvalidPropertyException.class) to @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) to handle all exceptions or you have to mention each exception...